# How to filter and sort few gb of data?

Tags: java, database, bigdata

I have 36gb big file which has about 600 milion lines of data in this structure:

```
LogID,SensorID,ValueNumeric,ValueString,DateAdded,VariableName,Name   
1215220724,1182,1,0000,,2016-01-04 12:56:57.7770000,Scan_Frequency,MIC_2
```

I am only interested in date, value, variable name and stream (name). Problem is that there is a lot of duplicate entrys and that data is not ordered by date.

My current solution is that I go trough first 100.000 lines, read name of the variables (there 833 of them) and create a table in DB for each of them. For primary key I use date(I had cut off seconds and milliseconds), so I DB will be free from duplicates. I know that this is not the best to have string for primary key.

Then I read the file again and enter that data in the tables, but it's to slow. My estimation is that I should have at least 10x less lines in the end.

Does anyone have a better idea, how to read such a big file and sort it by date and remove duplicates. It would be enough to save data for 5 min intervals.

Comment: Why is this tagged with Derby? Can't you sort using it?

Comment: 833 variables for every single sample?

Comment: There is not enough here for us to be able to answer this question.  We don't know anything about the data, the end goal, or the attempted solution.  Thus anything we suggest here will only be speculation, and not necessarily helpful for your needs.

Comment: @cricket_007 my current solution currently uses derby.
variables for every time period, which should be 1 minute, but there can be 3 entries for a variable inside 1 minute period

Comment: @JoeC I would like to remove duplicate data and sort it by time, so that I reduce the size of data and that we will be able to analyze it, since now is to no use, because it's not ordered by time. Latter I will split file in 7 files, by it's "Name" parameter

Comment: Obviously data doesn't reasonably fit in memory, so have you tried something like Apache Spark or a Hive database?

Comment: You'd be better off using Hadoop/Spark

Comment: The answer is pretty much "throw everything into a database". The best way to do that would depend heavily on details you didn't specify here and the specific database you choose to use.

Comment: Why on earth would you create a **table** for each variable in your file? If we're just talking about a single CSV file, that makes absolutely no sense. Either put everything into a single table or apply more complex logic to say things like "we can get User Name from User ID, thus those should probably go in a User table with a UserID foreign key in our primary table". Also, it doesn't really make sense to do 100k lines at a time - until you actually find that importing is a problem and you need to do things manually, just assume the database will do what's best if given everything in batch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use an [Elasticsearch + Logstash](https://www.elastic.co/products) based solution (they are free and work very well with their installation defaults). Logstash is designed to ingest data from several sources (including CSV files) and Elasticsearch is a NoSql database that does an amazing job both indexing documents and querying them.

See [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43701016/import-csv-into-elasticsearch) for a starting point, and [here is the documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Your database will offer a tool to import csv files directly. This is most likely much faster than using JDBC. Futhermore, chances are high it also offers a tool to remove the duplicates you mention during the import. Once you have the data in the database it will take care of sorting the data for you. 
Just to give you an example: If you were using MySQL there is the MySQL import utility [mysqlimport](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqlimport.html) which also offers an option to remove duplicates during the import using [--replace](http://duhttps://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqlimport.html).